# How can I get the current URL while clicking on the browser back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
window.onpopstate  = function() {
    console.log(window.location.href);
    return false;
});
```

Assume I'm currently in this path:

```
http://example.com/page2
```

Then I click on the back button of the browser. In this case, code above prints this:

```
http://example.com/page1
```

While the expected result is:

```
http://example.com/page2
```

Because ^ is the current URL (before pressing back button). Any idea how can I get that?

Comment: Is your solution entirely javascript?  MVC?  What is your serverside language?

Comment: @objectivelyC Is it important? I use PHP for backend.

Comment: First thought I would store the url in a PHP session variable on page2 load and then access it with javascript on page1.

Answer (score 0):

On load push the url into a stack of your own defined in window object. later when you click back you log that out.

Comment: Actually that's not just one time .. it's an array urls when you click on the back button.

Comment: i did not get you. pop out the latest url from that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onpopstate  = function() {
    console.log(document.referrer);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.onbeforeunload`, window.location.href should still be the same URL...